# Run a command on items in file using Ansible

Tags: for-loop, ansible

I am looking for a way to run a command like smartctl on a file containing device names like /dev/sda; (one per line). The ansible playbook should be able to read each line and make it an arg to the command.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. There are sites where you can hire programmers and DevOps to write code for your. SO is not one of them. You need to show us some code to see how we can help you. What did you try so far ?

Comment: This question seems too short. May be little more detail on your question is required.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<file_with_smartctl_args xargs -n1 smartctl
```

Replace file_with_smartctl_args with the file (complete path!) that contains the names of the files (arguments) you want to pass to smartctl. This will run "smartctl" one time for EACH of the lines (arguments) in the file.

Example:

If the file */usr/me/smartctl_args* contains the following text:
file1
file2
file3

The command:

```
</usr/me/smartctl_args xargs -n1 smartctl
```

Will run *smartctl* 3 times (since the file has 3 lines in it), like this:

```
smartctl file1
smartctl file2
smartctl file3
```

The initial *<* tells the Unix shell that your "standard input" is going to come from the filename that follows (*/usr/me/smartctl_args*). Then, *xargs* will convert the "standard input" to command arguments, the *-n1* option causes *xargs* to execute the command (*smartctl*) once for each argument.

Comment: Yeah I am looking for something like that, and be part of an ansible playbook.

Comment: Hey Shayne, your comments are OK, but I was still expecting an answer to my problem. Thanks